# CREATE TABLE syntax error in mysql 6.3/python 3.5

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using python to create a table in a mysql 6.3. The code worked great when using sqlite and is now throwing the following error.

pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `tokyo` REAL, primary key (rowid))' at line 1")

the code is

```
import pymysql
conn=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='password',db='testschema',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
a=conn.cursor()
sql='''CREATE TABLE pressure (rowid INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, date_time, 
    tokyo REAL, primary key (rowid));'''
a.execute(sql)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: ... `date_time` - what is this supposed to be? add some type to it maybe? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: Does the query work outside of your python script (against a MySQL instance not SQLite)?

Comment: I deleted the date_time column and it works great.  Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the *datatype* for the `date_time` column, say `DATETIME`:

```
sql='''CREATE TABLE pressure (rowid INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, date_time DATETIME, tokyo REAL, primary key (rowid));'''
```

---

Reference:

[Create Table syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

Type is not added to datetime column..

Change table creation syntax like below.

```sql
CREATE TABLE pressure (rowid INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, date_time datetime , 
tokyo REAL, primary key (rowid));
```